# C# - Create Variable Accessible Through Whole Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a connection string placed throughout my whole project, and would like to be able to bury it away from anyone who may be able to find it when I put my project into production. How can I create a string outside of my .cs files that contains this connection string that can be used inside of my .cs files?

I have tried to Google search this and have had no luck finding any answers.

Comment: If your program needs it, then there is no way. You _could_ use secure strings and some cryptography, but at some point the string will be in memory somehow anyway, even if it's hard to find.
The proper architecture design is to use credentials to connect to a remote service that will provide the data, and only this server application connects to the database, and thus there is no need to share the connection string anywhere at the client's location.

Comment: Probably you want to use something like `string connString = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Work\\connString.txt")`. However, if someone gets access to your Prod environment, hiding the connection string would probably not help too much

Comment: You should use configuration and settings files. When your app start, it reads configuration settings (connection strings included)

Comment: @MiladGhafoori but it won't be hidden for a user that try to find it in binary / files when in production, it seems that's what OP wants.

Comment: @MiladGhafoori your suggestion might be what I'm looking for. How might I do that?

Comment: Are you using dotnet core?

Comment: Yeah. I have an appsettings.json file if that would be an applicable spot to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dotnet Core, consider using configuration files. When your app start, it reads configuration settings (connection strings included). This will separate your configuration values from your code. Take a look at this:

[Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a textfile out of your project and write your value in there.
Then you access it again with a [FileReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-text-from-a-file).

Another way is to write it in your [configuration files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/store-custom-information-config-file)
or decrypt it as good as you can.

A full security to hide your ConnectionString from others is unfortunately not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can create TEXT file with encrypted string inside folder of project, than whenever you need it decrypt an use it